# Add a Google Earth Enterprise globe (from geserver) to QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, web-mapping, web-service, google-earth-enterprise

I am managing Google Earth Enterprise, where I can add data to Fusion, push it to geserver and then publish it to Google Earth Enterprise clients on people's computers. But the people need to add a database by typing in a URL containing e.g. geserver.it.firm.com/globe1/ and no other credentials are needed. I'm assuming credentials are indirectly processed because they need to login to their computers.

I'm wondering if it's possible to add this data into QGIS? 
I've tried adding Layers using WMS --> New Connection -->.. for name i just put '`Globe1`' and for URL I put `http://geserver.it.firm.com/globe1` but it says "Failed to download capabilities"
[image]

Is it possible to add this data into QGIS somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to link directly to a globe file, which would be a .glb file. That's not a file format supported by QGIS (at least it's not mentioned on the [QGIS "supported data" page](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html)).

QGIS does support WMS layers, and Google Earth Enterprise is capable of providing WMS layers. QGIS is even mentioned in the GEE documentation as a "supported client."

> GEE Server supports the OpenGIS Web Map Service Interface Standard (WMS), which provides a standard HTTP interface to request map images from one or more published geospatial databases.  One of the benefits of using the WMS standard is that supported clients can request images from multiple WMS servers and then combine those mapping images into a single view.  Because the WMS standard is used to fetch the images, they can easily be overlaid on one another.  Supported clients include **QGIS**, ArcGIS/ArcGIS Explorer Desktop, and Google Earth Pro/EC

-source: [Google Earth Enterprise Documentation: Overview](http://www.opengee.org/geedocs/answer/6353404.html)

However, GEE doesn't provide WMS support by default. You have to set it up. Here are [instructions for setting up WMS support in a GEE database](http://www.opengee.org/geedocs/answer/4441137.html):

> Setting up Google Earth Enterprise Server 5.x Support for WMS To
>   enable WMS for a database that you want to publish:
>
> 1. In the GEE Server Admin console, click Databases.
> 2. Check the box next to the database you want to publish.
> 3. Next to Serve WMS, select On.
> 4. Click Publish.
>
> Publishing a 2D Fusion or 2D portable database with Serve WMS turned on publishes both to GEE Server and WMS; it's not necessary to publish twice.
>
> Databases that have WMS enabled are identified as such with a WMS
>   label in the description.